# Как увидеть список устройств в Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: настройка, драйвер, железо, ubuntu

В моём случае мне необходимо просмотреть, есть ли на ноутбуке bluetooth. Но так как просмотр всех устройств, как в диспетчере устройств windows, возникает регулярно, то решил узнать есть ли какая желательно графическая утилита для просмотра списка устройств.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам нашел отличную графическую утилиту по типу everest

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ lspci
```

А если добавить ключ -k, то можно увидеть ещё и модули, которые используют устройства. Очень полезно, когда что-нибудь не заводится - это больше к пользователям gentoo (при использовании livecd).